# Setting the visibility of a tab

Tags: javascript, html, visualforce

Hello I am passing an ID to a popup window and based on that ID I want to set a specific tab to visible or not. The Id being passed is "key2" and I am pulling that from the URL. The Id of the tab is "tabTwo". Below is my code that I have so far, the alert fires but the tab is still visible. Let me know if you have any thoughts on why this tab is still visible, thanks.

```
window.onload = function DealVis()
               {
                   var url = document.URL;
                   if(url.indexOf("key2") != -1)
                   {
                       alert("got it");
                       document.getElementById("tabTwo").style.visibility="hidden";
                   }
               }
```

HTML for tagTwo

```
<apex:tab label="New Land Deal" name="tab2" id="tabTwo">

    <apex:pageBlock id="newLandDeal" title="New Land Deal" >

      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveNewLandDeal}" value="Save"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageMessages />

      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
       <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Land_Deal__c.FieldSets.NewLandDeal}" var="f"> 
          <apex:inputField value="{!landDeal[f]}"/> 
       </apex:repeat> 

      </apex:pageBlockSection> 
    </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:tab>
```

Comment: Are there any messages in the JS console?

Comment: Could you post the HTML for that tabTwo?

Comment: Besides the Alert, No.

Comment: added the html for tagTwo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this `alert(document.getElementById("tabTwo"))` next to the `alert("got it");` and check if it can find your `tabTwo` element.

1- I think the problem might be the `tabTwo` is not your tab's ID.

or

2- your tab is being loaded after when `window.onload` happens. which is probably because your tabs is being created based on some `Ajax` requests and you have to wait until it is done.

Comment: Yeah it came up with an alert that is blank so it probably is not finding the ID

Comment: Im not sure why it would not be finding the ID thought because if it isn't then how would I code the id in without the id="tabTwo" ?

Comment: if you could make sure that the ID is correct but javascript can't find it, it is mostly because of your ajax requests, then you have to find the right listener instead of `window.onload` to run your code.

Comment: That makes sense, I am not the best with javascript so I am not sure what else I would use in place of windows.onload

Comment: open your Developer Tools and run this in console `document.getElementById("tabTwo")` and check if it has result, and let me know

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: it returned null, I also added a line to my html above to show the tag id name, I realized that I forgot it initially

Comment: firefox is the browser I use

Comment: have you installed firebug on your firefox. it is a firefox plugin which is by far better than firefox Developer Tools.

Comment: BTW, try right click and `Inspect Element` on your tab and find out what your tab ID is.

Comment: I am using Firebug for the Development Console. The following is what I find when I check the HTML:

Comment: <textarea onblur="javascript:editArea.textareaFocused=false;" onfocus="javascript:editArea.textareaFocused=true;" onchange="editArea.execCommand(&quot;onchange&quot;);" wrap="off" id="textarea" classname="null hidden" class="null hidden" style="font-family: monospace; font-size: 10pt; line-height: 16px; width: 1969px; height: 1904px;" spellcheck="false">    </textarea>

Comment: it is not what I expected to see, I don't know what does it mean but as far as I'm concerned your server side is Oracle Apex and I think it has its own javascript library and also it changes the client side element IDs

Comment: If your page loads then you should try `Inspect Element` exactly on your tab UI object and find the right html element